# Reopen a question that is edited with a solution?

Tags: discussion

I've noticed a few questions in the "Reopen Votes" queue that are there because they have been edited since being closed, specifically with an answer to the problem, for example [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/21620825).

What is the appropriate action here? Vote to Reopen, or Leave Closed?

Comment: I can't think of any close reason where adding an answer to the question would make the question on-topic. The answer isn't even supposed to be in the question.

Comment: @BSMP indeed, but I guess that given the question has been closed they can't post the solution as an answer.

Comment: Yes, that's also why people post comments in answers to get around the rep limit. The point remains that the question is not improved by having an answer tacked onto it.

Comment: If the answer is valuable then that can be a saving grace for the close-worthy question, but that's really not the case here.

Comment: In this case the question was closed as duplicate, and OP's "solution" is just an exact copy-paste of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33034768/5267751), so... is the answer even worth posting?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Possibility or presence of an answer does not make question on-topic. In most cases “leave closed” is the right action. You may consider rolling back edit that added the answer if you believe question is good to stay on the site as signpost duplicate.

One case where you can consider to reopen is unclear question made clear by suggested answer - in this case you need to edit question in shape so it is clear and “answer” would actually answer it. Since you can’t keep answer in the question you would have to watch the question and post answer later if it is reopened. This requires significant effort and potentially controversial edits - maybe you found that pearl of a question...

Comment: Sorry, completely forgot about this question, probably something to do with the time of year. As @user202729 pointed out, the answer is just a cut and paste from the duplicate which I should have picked up on anyway and voted "leave closed". I think your second paragraph is a wonderfully noble idea but might be a bit beyond most peoples (including probably mine) effort levels.